# Audio player issue with flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I was designing an audio player, the slider isn't working and the audio keeps on playing even when I press pause.  I have attached the code and log.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';



import '../login.dart';


import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class bestPractises extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _bestPractises();
  }
}

class _bestPractises extends State<bestPractises> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
  AudioPlayer audioPlayer= new AudioPlayer();
  Duration duration = new Duration();
  Duration position = new Duration();
  bool playing = false;





  String Lat = "",
      Lng = "";
  List<DropdownMenuItem> primtopicsitems = [];
  String slctprimtopics = "",slcttopics="";
  List<ImageProductSaleModel> imageList = new List();
  List<UImodel> bpListUIModel = new List();
  List<UImodel> topicListUIModel = new List();
  List<DropdownMenuItem> bestpractitems = [],topicitems=[];
  File farmerImageFile;
  String AudioBase64 = "";
  String audioPath = "";
  bool isRecord = false;
  TextEditingController remarksController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController txtmesgController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController precadvicController = new TextEditingController();

  File fileMedia;
  MediaSource source;
  String vedio64 = "";

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("inistate");
    initvalues();
    getLocation();

   // _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(dataSource);
    //_initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
    //_controller.setLooping(true);


    // getClientData();
  }

  void dispose() {
    //_controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }



  Future<void> initvalues() async {
    List bpList = await db.RawQuery('select * from animalCatalog where catalog_code=\'140\'');
    print('bpList ' + bpList.toString());
    bpListUIModel = new List();
    bestpractitems.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < bpList.length; i++) {
      String ptName = bpList[i]["property_value"].toString();
      String ptCode = bpList[i]["DISP_SEQ"].toString();

      var uimodel = new UImodel(ptName, ptCode);
      bpListUIModel.add(uimodel);
      setState(() {
        bestpractitems.add(DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(ptName),
          value: ptCode,
        ));
      });
    }

    List topicList = await db.RawQuery('select * from animalCatalog where catalog_code=\'140\'');
    print('topicList ' + topicList.toString());
    topicListUIModel = new List();
    topicitems.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < topicList.length; i++) {
      String topicName = topicList[i]["property_value"].toString();
      String topicCode = topicList[i]["DISP_SEQ"].toString();

      var uimodel = new UImodel(topicName, topicCode);
      topicListUIModel.add(uimodel);
      setState(() {
        topicitems.add(DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(topicName),
          value: topicCode,
        ));
      });
    }
  }

  Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
    return Alert(
      context: context,
      type: AlertType.warning,
      title: "Cancel",
      desc: "Are you sure want to cancel?",
      buttons: [
        DialogButton(
          child: Text(
            "Yes",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          width: 120,
        ),
        DialogButton(
          child: Text(
            "No",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          width: 120,
        )
      ],
    ).show() ??
        false;
  }

  void getLocation() async {
    bool isLocationEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (isLocationEnabled) {
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

      print("latitude :" +
          position.latitude.toString() +
          " longitude: " +
          position.longitude.toString());
      setState(() {
        Lat = position.latitude.toString();
        Lng = position.longitude.toString();
      });
    } else {
      Alert(
          context: context,
          title: "Information",
          desc: "GPS Location not enabled",
          buttons: [
            DialogButton(
              child: Text(
                "OK",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              color: Colors.green,
            )
          ]).show();
    }
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
        child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
                onPressed: () {
                  _onBackPressed();
                }),
            title: Text(
              'Best Practices',
              style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
            ),
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            brightness: Brightness.light,
          ),
          body: Container(

              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    children: _getbpListings(
                        context), // <<<<< Note this change for the return type
                  ),
                  flex: 8,
                ),
              ])),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _getbpListings(BuildContext context) {
    List listings = List<Widget>();

    listings.add(txt_label(
        "Primary Topic", Colors.black, 16.0, false));
    listings.add(singlesearchDropdown(
        itemlist: bestpractitems,
        selecteditem: slctprimtopics,
        hint: "Select the Primary Topic",
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            slctprimtopics = value;
          });
        }));

    listings.add(txt_label(
        "Topic", Colors.black, 16.0, false));
    listings.add(singlesearchDropdown(
        itemlist: topicitems,
        selecteditem: slcttopics,
        hint: "Select the Topic",
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            slcttopics = value;
          });
        }));

    // listings.add(txt_label(
    //     "\nText Messages  ", Colors.black, 16.0, false));

    listings.add(Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: txt_label(
                    "\nText Messages  ", Colors.black, 16.0, false)
                //),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: txt_label(
                    "\nBuyer 1  ", Colors.black, 16.0, false)
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

      ],
    ),

    );

    // listings
    //     .add(txtfield_dynamic("", txtmesgController, true));

    listings.add(Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: txt_label(
                      "\nPrecautionary \n Advices  ", Colors.black, 16.0, false)
                //),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 4,
                  child: txt_label(
                      "\n This is the Advisory Message  ", Colors.black, 16.0, false)
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

      ],
    ),

    );

    // listings.add(txt_label(
    //     "Precautionary Advices", Colors.black, 16.0, false));
    //
    // listings
    //     .add(txtfield_dynamic("", precadvicController, true));

    listings.add(Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: txt_label(
                      "\nManuals  ", Colors.black, 16.0, false)
                //),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 4,
                  child: txt_label(
                      "\n This is the Advisory Message  ", Colors.black, 16.0, false)
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

      ],
    ),

    );

    // listings.add(txt_label(
    //     "Manuals          ", Colors.black, 16.0, false));
    //
    // listings
    //     .add(txtfield_dynamic("", precadvicController, true));


    listings.add(txt_label("\nPhotos of the Advices", Colors.black, 16.0, false));

    listings.add( Row(
      children: [

           Image(
            image: AssetImage('images/1.jpg'),
             height: 375,
             width: 375,
          ),


        const SizedBox(height: 24),



      ],
    ),
    );


  /*  listings.add( Row(
       FutureBuilder (
        future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
        builder: (context,snapshot)
    {
      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
        {
          return AspectRatio(aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
            child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
          );
    }else {
        return Center(
          child : CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
        },
      ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onpressed : (){
            setState(() {
              if(_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                _controller.pause();
              } else {
                _controller.play();
              }
            });
          }

        child:
            Icon(_controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow),
    ),
    ),
    ); */

    // listings.add(img_picker(
    //     label: "Photos of the Advices \*",
    //     onPressed: () {
    //       getImage();
    //     },
    //     filename: farmerImageFile,
    //     ondelete: () {
    //       ondelete();
    //     }));



    listings.add(txt_label("Video", Colors.black, 16.0, false));

    listings.add( Row(
      children: [
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('\Video'),
          onPressed: () => capture(MediaSource.video),
          color: Colors.green,
          textColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 24),
        Expanded(
          child: fileMedia == null
              ? Container()
              : (source == MediaSource.video
              ? Column(
            children: [
              VideoWidget(fileMedia),
            ],
          )
              : Container()),
        ),


      ],
    ),
    );

    listings.add(txt_label("\nAudio", Colors.black, 16.0, false));

    listings.add(Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget> [
          //Image(image: AssetImage(''),),

          slider(),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              getAudio();
            },
              child:Icon(
              playing == false
                  ? Icons.play_circle_outline
                  : Icons.pause_circle_outline,
                size: 50,
                color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          )

        ],
      ),
    ),
    );

    listings.add(btn_dynamic(
        label: "Audio",
        bgcolor: Colors.green,
        txtcolor: Colors.white,
        fontsize: 18.0,
        centerRight: Alignment.centerLeft,
        margin: 10.0,
        btnSubmit: () async {
          audioPath = await Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AudioRecorder()));

          File audioFile = new File(audioPath);
          List<int> fileBytes = await audioFile.readAsBytes();
          AudioBase64 = base64Encode(fileBytes);

          setState(() {
            isRecord = true;
          });
        }));
    if (isRecord) {
      listings.add(Container(
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
        height: 40,
        child: Center(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Center(
                    child: txt_label(
                        audioPath.split('/').last, Colors.white, 14.0, false)),
                flex: 3,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isRecord = false;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.red)),
                flex: 1,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }

    listings.add(txt_label("\nRemarks", Colors.black, 14.0, false));
    listings.add(txtfield_dynamic("Remarks", remarksController, true));

    /* listings.add(Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Cancel',
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  _onBackPressed();
                },
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),

          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Submit',
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  _bestpractisessubmit();
                },
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //
        ],
      ),
    )); */
    return listings;
  }

  Widget slider() {
    return Slider.adaptive(
      min:  0.0,
      value: position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
      max: duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
      onChanged : (double value) {
        setState(() {
          audioPlayer.seek(new Duration(seconds: value.toInt()));

        });
      }
    );
  }

  void getAudio() async {
    var url = "https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kalimba.mp3";

    if (playing) {
      var res = await audioPlayer.pause();
      if(res == 1) {
        setState(() {
          playing = false;
        });
      }

    } else {
      var res = await audioPlayer.play(url,isLocal: true);
      if(res == 1) {
        setState(() {
          playing = true;
        });
      }
    }
    audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((Duration dd) {
      setState(() {
        duration = dd;
      });
    });
    audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((Duration dd) {
      setState(() {
        position = dd;
      });
    });

  }

  void _bestpractisessubmit() async{
    if (slctprimtopics == "") {
      errordialog(context, "Information",
          "Primary Topic should not be empty");
    }else if (slcttopics == ''){
      errordialog(context, "Information",
          "Topic should not be empty");
    }else{
      Alert(
        context: context,
        type: AlertType.info,
        title: "Information",
        desc: "Are you sure want to proceed?",
        buttons: [
          DialogButton(
            child: Text(
              "Yes",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
            ),
            onPressed: () {


              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },

            width: 120,
          ),
          DialogButton(
            child: Text(
              "No",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            width: 120,
          )
        ],
      ).show() ??
          false;
    }
  }

  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.platform
        .pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 30);
    setState(() {
        farmerImageFile = new File(image.path);
    });
  }

  void ondelete() {
    setState(() {
        if (farmerImageFile != null) {
          setState(() {
            farmerImageFile = null;
          });
        }

    });
  }

  Future capture(MediaSource source) async {
    setState(() {
      this.source = source;
      this.fileMedia = null;
    });

    final result = await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => SourcePage(),
        settings: RouteSettings(
          arguments: source,
        ),
      ),
    );

    if (result == null) {
      return;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        fileMedia = result;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

log:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception:
> setState() called after dispose(): _bestPractises#e42c5(lifecycle
> state: defunct, not mounted)
> This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent
> widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can
> occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation
> callback.
> The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check
> the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to
> ensure the object is still in the tree.
> This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State
> object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks,
> consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
> #0      State.setState. (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1052:9)
> #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1087:6)
> #2      _bestPractises.getAudio. (package:aftab/Screens/bestPractisesscreen.dart:611:7)
> #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
> #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
> #5      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
> #6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
> #7      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:14)
> #8      _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:706:11)
> #9      _PendingEvents.schedule. (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:663:7)
> #10     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1346:47)
> #11     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
> #12     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7)
> #13     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded. (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:23)
> #14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1354:13)
> #15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
> #16     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7)
> #17     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded. (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:23)
> #18     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
> #19     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)

Comment: You are calling setState() somewhere after calling dispose() of the widget. That is the reason for the error, just like the error log says. Please check and make sure no setState() methods are called after destroying the particular widget.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, resolved by wrapping all `setState` calls with:

```
if (mounted) {
  setState(() {});
}
```